# MPI for loop in c

Tags: c, mpi

I need to loop through a bi-dimensional array executing an operation on all the elements of the array, for some number of iterations.  Here is my code:

```
for (for_iters=0;for_iters<ITERS;for_iters++) 
   { 
     diff = 0.0;

     for (i=1;i<n;i++)
     {
       for (j=1;j<n;j++)
       {
         tmp = A[i][j];
         A[i][j] = 0.3*(A[I][j] + A[i][j-1] + A[i-1][j] + A[i][j+1] + A[i+1][j]);
       }

     }
     iters++;

    } /*for*/
}
```

The problem is to translate the above code to MPI. I think I could divide the elements of the array to make every process deal with a part of the array, but I have no idea how to make the outer loop if every line of the code its executed once per process? if I have 3 processes, would I create 3 external loops??

Comment: By outer loop do you mean the `for (for_iters=0;for_iters<ITERS;for_iters++)`? You can easily split the matrix computation by for instance making different processes perform computations on different matrix rows (and all associated columns). The actual first loop could be left as it is. You can also split the outer loop and have each process compute all matrix values.

Comment: Come to think of it, it makes little sense to parallelize the iterative outermost loop - you need previous solution in order to compute the current. In that case a simple parallelization is the first way i.e. the second loop.

Comment: But the n iteration nes all the results of n-1 iterations,if I split the outer loop I think I won't get this result

Comment: That's the second comment, also your current code has some typos. I suggest you first make a serial one, run it and confirm its validity, then move on to MPI. So if I were you I would simply split it using rows - like process 0 gets rows 0 to some Ni etc. and then computes across all columns - I would just split them evenly taking care of uneven-ness using like modulo. There are online resources for this one. You will also need to communicate the outer-boundary rows at the end of each iteration (i,j are known on the current process but i-1 and i+1 are not if on the boundary).